# Talend ORA-02289: sequence does not exist error?

Tags: oracle11g, talend

I have a table_1 with sequence ( I'm using Oracle 11g database) and I want to extract rows from another table to load them in my table_2 using Talend Open Studio, but I have this error : "ORA-02289: sequence does not exist error" someone can help me ?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're attempting to use a sequence that does not exist. If you're using a sequence in your SELECT statement then a sequence object with that name needs to exist. However, as this is your database, we don't have access to the data dictionary. The most we can do is what I've just suggested. If you're not using a sequence in your SELECT statement then please post the statement.

Comment: Yes it's true Sir. I had a problem that the shema had not the permession to access to the sequence. I had changed the shema and that work now. Thanks a lot Ben.

Answer (score 2):

Add the schema name to the beginning of the sequence name:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME.SEQUENCE_NAME FROM DUAL;
```